# Is it possible in salesforce to switch b/w 2 users?

Tags: configuration, salesforce, customization, apex

My requirement is I have 2 Roles NA and Pacific and I want a single user(specific user lets say Adam) to handle these 2 role's cases but at the same time other users with Role NA should not see cases of Pacific role and vice versa.
We have owner based sharing in our org where we shared cases on the basis of Roles.
I want a feature where Adam (my user) can switch b/w these users(NA role user and pacific Role user).

Please help I am open to every suggestion.

I try to call Apex from flow to change the role of my user ,but the problem in this approach is -
suppose I am NA role user and currently own a case(case no -123), this case(case no 123) must be shared with NA user role only, but when I switched my role from NA to Pacific by using flow that I had created what happens is the case(case no-123) got shared to Pacific role and unshared with NA role cause we have sharing based on Role and this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it, try these 2 and report back if it's not ideal.

Make "Adam" a manager of both teams, give him role above these in role hierarchy and he should see everything his subordinates see. (but his own cases won't be shared down)

or make him in "Pacific" role but create 2nd sharing rule.
Cases - Owner in role: NA - share with - group "Adam and friends" ;)
(make public group and make Adam the only member of that group)